# Extract letters before first number Windows batch file

Tags: batch-file

I'm making a batch program that will go through each line of a text file. Each line will have a similar format in that it is series of letters then either nothing or a number followed by more characters like so:

RRR14
AMRCC1M_08
TT

I need to be able to use both the entire string and just the letters before the first number while running the code (i.e. var1=RRR14 and var2=RRR), but I'm unsure how to extract just the leading letters since the length and values are different for each string. Also since there isn't guaranteed to be a number in the string, I'm not sure how to go about it.

EDIT: Using the suggested solution, I have a new problem. It seems that var2 isn't updating correctly. I run the code:

```
for /f "tokens=1" %%a in (%1.txt) do (
for /f "tokens=1 delims=0123456789" %%G in ("%%a") do set var2=%%G
echo %var2%
echo %%a
echo.
)
```

with all the ECHO's to try to debug and I get:

```
>set var2=RRR
JIKK
RRR14
```

where JIKK seems to come from JIKK8 (the last line in the text file). Not sure if I'm referencing the variable incorrectly or what's not working here

Comment: You are inside a parenthesized code block so now you have to reference the `var2` variable with delayed expansion enabled and use exclamation instead of percent symbols to reference.  Regardless of that.  Why bother using `var2`.  Just create another parenthesized code block and use the FOR variable instead.  I will update my answer with fixes to your new code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `FOR /F` command and use all 10 numbers as the `DELIMS` options.

So in your example.

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=1 delims=0123456789" %%G IN ("RRR14") DO SET var2=%%G
```

So based on the new code you updated within your question you have two options.

The first option is to just create another parenthesized code block and use the FOR variable directly.

```
@ECHO OFF
for /f "tokens=1" %%a in (%1.txt) do (
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=0123456789" %%G in ("%%a") do (
        echo %G%
        echo %%a
        echo.
    )
)
```

Your second option is to use delayed expansion to reference the variable without an additional parenthesized code block.

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1" %%a in (%1.txt) do (
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=0123456789" %%G in ("%%a") do set "var2=%%G"
    echo !var2!
    echo %%a
    echo.
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I think I was overthinking what I had to do.

Comment: @tg94, a lot of people don't understand the use of TOKENS and DELIMS with a FOR /F command. Once you do though, its like having an epiphany and then the possibilities of what you can do with the command becomes endless.

Comment: @tg94, edit your question with the code you are using. Do not put it in a comment.  Message me back when you have updated your question with the code you are using.